# Can't get buttons to work wx.python (ubuntu 12.04 LTS )

Tags: application-development, python

```
try:
    import wx
except ImportError:
    print 'Module not found'

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(parent,id ):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        button = wx.Button(panel,label = 'close',size = (50,50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnCloseMe,button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE,self.OnCloseWindow)

    def OnCloseMe(self,event):
        self.Close(True)

    def OncloseWindow(self,event):
        self.Destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = wx.Frame(parent = None, id =-1,title = 'Widget',size = (300,100))
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Hi guys ,the code above is just to create a button in wxpython.but everytime i run the code ,only the Frame appears,no buttons or whatsoever inside,just blank.i tried to reinstall the wxpython module but no luck. My second question is whenever i try to initialize say, title = 'widget', size= (300,100) in the frame constructor like wx.Frame.init(self,parent,id,title ='widget',size = (300,100) it does not work, i have to do it through this line: frame = wx.Frame(parent = None, id =-1,title = 'Widget',size = (300,100)) why is that so.thanks.

Comment: This question is not specific to Ubuntu and is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong Frame. You create standard `wx.Frame`, not your `Frame(wx.Frame)`.
I changed name to `MyFrame` to make this name more uniqe.

```
try:
    import wx
except ImportError:
    print 'Module not found'

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent,id ):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id,)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        button = wx.Button(panel, label='close', size=(50,50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCloseMe, button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnCloseWindow)

    def OnCloseMe(self,event):
        self.Close(True)

    def OnCloseWindow(self,event): # not OncloseWindow
        self.Destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    #frame = wx.Frame(parent=None, id=-1, title='Widget', size=(300,100)) 
    frame = MyFrame(parent=None, id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```